# AngularJS $q.defer() with jasmine done(): promise.then function not getting called

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine

Can someone help me understand why this isn't working? I'm using Jasmine's `both` function to wait for the promise.then function too be called and make an assertion. But it times out before it is called.

```
describe('greeting', function(){
    var greeting = 'hello';

    it('should call promise.then', function(done) {
        inject(function ($q) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(greeting);

            deferred.promise.then(function (greeting) {
                expect(greeting).toEqual('hello');
                done();
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The `then` function doesn't get called and Jasmine times out with this message:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do a `$scope.$apply` to trigger the angular digest cycle, like this:

```
inject(function ($q, $rootScope) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   deferred.resolve(greeting);

   deferred.promise.then(function (greeting) {
      expect(greeting).toEqual('hello');
      done();
   });
   $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

Should fix the issue